# How to change maximum password age for a single local account in Win7 home?

Tags: windows-7, password-management

I'd like to change maximum password age for a single user, using Windows 7 home.
I want user to be enforced to change password every 30 days.

I have already found this command, but unfortunately it applies new settings for every user.

> net accounts /maxpwage:30

So, how can I enforce password change after 30 days just for one user?

Comment: Are you trying to force a password chnage, prevent the password from having to chnage, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  Please edit your question to clarify the reason you are doing this, and yes, the reason is really really relevant

Comment: @Ramhound I have two accounts on system, admin (mine) and standard user. I want to force him to change his password every 30 days but account of mine should stay unchanged.

Comment: Make the policy change then configure your user account so the password never expires.

Comment: @Ramhound Sounds more like an answer than comment

Comment: I normally would but I don’t have an appropriate VM to use for screenshots

Comment: @Ramhound Don't set the bar so high that answers fail to make it over. I also haven't tested your idea... and it might be wrong. But I think that's okay really. Perfect questions are rare, and even good ones like this sholdn't require a VM for an answer when too many comments mostly get frowned upon given the chat room feature.

But Google doesn't look there...

Comment: You are right.  I shouldn’t even replied to any of your comments.  If I get a chance to configure a VM I will submit an answer.